# Access property value from handler

Tags: instance, clips

Usually to access an instance's property I write:

```
(defrule check-property
    ?room <- (object (is-a ROOM) (property ?property))        
    =>
    (printout ?*debug-print* "Property is " ?property crlf))
```

Is there a quickest way to call the property directly from the handler?

For example (?room:property is not a valid syntax):

```
(defrule check-property
        ?room <- (object (is-a ROOM))        
        =>
        (printout ?*debug-print* "Property is " ?room:property crlf))
```

Thank you
Nic

Answer (score 0):

The short-hand notation is only supported in message handlers and instance queries, but that would be a nice feature to add.

Comment: Do you have a site/form where I can add a nice-to-have feature?